# Convert string into date form

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

I have a column with string **partition=201707070800**, I need to convert this to **2017-07-08** , How can we achieve this is hive ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substring function

```
select concat(substr(<column-string-date>,0,4),'-',substr(<column-string-date>,5,2),'-',substr(<column-string-date>,9,2)) from <table-name>;
```

this should give output like 2017-07-08